# What can I do to fix my app?

Tags: java, android, camera

I have a problem with my camera app, which is that when I take a photo I can see it in the imageview, but when I turn my phone or close the app and reopen it, the image disappears.

***My code->***

```
public class semana1 extends Activity {

    Button btnfoto1;
    ImageView imgs1;
    static final int CAM_REQUEST=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.semana1);
        btnfoto1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnfoto1);
        imgs1= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgs1);
        btnfoto1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent int1=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File file=getfile();
                int1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                startActivityForResult(int1,CAM_REQUEST);

            }
        });

    }
    private File getFile()
    {
        File folder=new File("sdcard/Progress");

        if(!folder.exists())
        {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        File image_file=new File(folder,"image1.jpg");
        return image_file;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        String path = "sdcard/Progress/image1.jpg";

        imgs1.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly have you done on your side to validate the behavior and diagnose it.

Comment: @JoxTraex when I use my app and I turn my phne, the image disappears, but I can see it in my files.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the [activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) of an app.

Now to point you in somewhat the right direction. When you close your app, the system stops the app and might later kill it. The reason why your image disappears is because you haven implemented a way for your app to save the state it was in before hand.

Therefore, you should probably implement:

```
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // code where you tell the app to save the image
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // code where you tell the app to save the image
}
```